# Building compiler in Python: determining integer values

Tags: python, compiler-construction

I'm building a compiler for a language called Jack (similar to Java). I'm working on my tokenizer, but I'm having trouble trying to determine if a token in the file is an integer. Here is how I'm implementing reserved words in the language as well as symbols:

```
def tokenType(self):
    if self.token in ['class', 'constructor', 'function', 'method', 'field', 'static', 'var', 'int', 'char', 'boolean', 'void', 'true', 'false', 'null', 'this', 'let', 'do', 'if', 'else', 'while', 'return']:
        return 'KEYWORD'

    elif self.token in ['{', '}', '(', ')', '[', ']',  '.', ',', ';', '+', '-', '*' ,'/', '&', '|', '<', '>', '=', '~']:
        return 'SYMBOL'
```

However, I'm not sure how I would determine if the token was an integer between 0 and 32767. Is there a way to search for a range of values easily?

Comment: @JMK In Python this is spelled as 0 <= ... <= 32767.

Answer (score 4):

```
elif self.token.isdigit() and 0 <= int(self.token) < 32768:
    return 'INTEGER'
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
elif self.token.isdigit():
    return 'INTEGER_LITERAL'
```